# "Tell Your Friends" - a mysterious e-mail that landed in my inbox [Part 2 of 6]

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Following the mystery embedded in [the initial puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40443/tell-your-friends-a-mysterious-email-that-landed-in-my-inbox)...

---

> **Note:** Sorry, I messed up. I've re-uploaded the image in PNG format. Quality should be back.

Congratulations! Through much hard work, you've managed to solve the initial puzzle and have apparently pleased your unknown host, who sends his regards and more instructions:

> Congratulations. You've passed the first test.
>
> Each level from here on out will contain a hidden message of some kind. Good luck, and keep your wits about you. Only five more challenges to go.
>
> Level 2:
>   https://www.noreallyitis.me/FF0A86.png
>   [**Ed. Note:** The link is dead now, but the below image is a mirror hosted on Imgur. It should suffice for this challenge]

[image: Imgur]

Not wanting to disappoint your mysterious host, you get to work.

---

**Note**: This puzzle was not created by me, but it does have a known solution now. I've received permissions from the original author (`me@noreallyitis.me`) to upload them here.

Comment: FF0A86 is the Hex code for that colour's rgb value - (255, 10, 134)

Comment: @naffarn - is every pixel the same colour, or are there some stray pixels that have a slightly different value?

Comment: @YowE3K I can't tell, on my phone. But the fact that there are 5 more challenges including this one means that "6 levels deep" in the original puzzle referred to the puzzle chain as a whole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The photo says:

> Codebreaker

Because:

> [image: Clue]
>  The letters are an anagram

Answer (score 1):

The fact that there is only an image leads me to suspect that there is something more to it.

By lowering the contrast drastically I get this image:

[image: Low contrast]

I can't make anything of it but it proves the image isn't just a pink square (I hope)

Lowering the contrast even further just leaves a blue square.

Comment: I've uploaded a cleaner version of the image. My apologies. ^~^``