# “Tell Your Friends” - a mysterious e-mail that landed in my inbox [Part 3 of 6]

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Following your solution of [part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40491/tell-your-friends-a-mysterious-e-mail-that-landed-in-my-inbox-part-2-of) and the Editor screwing up beyond belief, I present to you... PART 3!

---

You send the answer back to our Mysterious Host. Within a blink of an eye, a new puzzle appears for you to solve:

```
Playing for Stavation
0-439-02348-3
9-4-1
188-1-14
59-3-59
189-2-27
317-3-2
```

You vainly look around for a hint in the latest message, but see none. What does our Host have planned?

```
*BLEEP* Incoming message, from: host@puzzle
-------------------------------------------
I see that you've been stuck here for a whi
le now. So, I only thought it be fair to gi
ve you a hint. It's not the words.
[Connection to host@puzzle terminated]

[Connection re-established by host@puzzle]
*BLEEP* Incoming message, from: host@puzzle
-------------------------------------------
So I see it's been a while and there's stil
l no right answer. Perhaps this is too hard
? Nevertheless, one more hint. You're looki
ng at something too big. Maybe something sm
aller? 

*BLEEP* Incoming message, from op@puzzle
------------------------------------------
IadmirehowfaryouvegottensofarYoushouldbeco
untinglikeyouarebutyouwerecountingthewrong
thingsPerhapsthisfinalmessagewillhelp
```

---

Note: This puzzle was not created by me, but it does have a known solution now. I've received permissions from the original author (`me@noreallyitis.me`) to upload them here. This text is *exactly* as it appears in the original puzzle.

*Edit from Original Author*: The PDF you guys are using is a bit off, here is a slightly modified cipher you can use for the PDF:

```
10-4-1
187-1-24
59-3-59
188-1-27
313-3-2
```

Comment: stavation or starvation? First line

Comment: @Areeb That is verbatim from the puzzle, and it appeared there as `Stavation`. Make of that as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure it wasn't a typo

Comment: http://www.directtextbook.com/isbn/9780439023481

Comment: http://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/BD021B Color of catching fire?

Comment: @bleh so it's something to do with Hunger Games, Heck, it probably is "Hunger Games"

Comment: @bleh probably a book cipher using that edition

Comment: This series reminds me a lot of www.amnesya.com - great puzzle series, pretty hard though.

Comment: @KazWolfe You got it?

Comment: @bleh Yep. OP gave a hint so I'll probably release it tomorrow

Comment: As @bleh said `0-439-02348-3` is the ISBN number from the hunger games trilogy. I have it on Amazon but i don't have the page number on my ebook. I'm pretty sure all the number but the first are Page-Paragraph-line since the first number goes up to189 (page number), the second number goes up to 4 (paragraph number - might be the line number as well but it just goes up to 4, it seems appropaite it is the apragraph.) and the third number goes up to 27 (which might be line number, word number on the apragraph or maybe even the `char`)

Comment: link to specific book http://www.kkoworld.com/kitablar/suzanna-kollinz-acliq-oyunlari-1-hisse-eng.pdf

Comment: @Miquel: The page numbers are off by 1, [according to CasperTheFriendlyCode in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31705514#31705514).

Comment: Actually, that whole PDF is a bit off from the edition I originally used. When making this puzzle, I originally intended it mainly for North American audiences, where I figured this book would be easy enough to pick up at a nearby library. I can re-write the cipher using the PDF, if you all need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what everyone else got, I used the code as

> page, paragraph, letter

and got

> LUCKY

Answer (score 3):

**Partial Answer**

We have 2 parts of the puzzle. The first part is:

```
Playing for Stavation
0-439-02348-3
```

Which refers to:

> `0-439-02348-3` is the [ISBN](http://www.directtextbook.com/isbn/9780439023481) for [The Hunger Games Book](http://www.kkoworld.com/kitablar/suzanna-kollinz-acliq-oyunlari-1-hisse-eng.pdf).

The second part we have:

```
9-4-1
188-1-14
59-3-59
189-2-27
317-3-2
```

Which might be a number of things but probably:

> We have 3 numbers, `x-y-z`. `x` refers to the **page number**. `y` refers to the **line number**. And then we have `z` which I suspect refers to the **`char` number**

Given the assumption given [in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31705514#31705514) about the pages which are `+-1` off:

If they are `+1`:

**9-4-1**

> 10-4-1 : `blue sky and soft breeze. The food’s wonderful, with the` - **b**

**188-1-14**

> 189-1-14 : `ment, and I do my best to pat them dry on my shirt. If I don’t` - **o**

**59-3-59**

> 60-3-59 : `smiling at the gawking crowd. He only stops when the train` - **a space**

**189-2-27**

> 190-2-27 : `which is pointless. She calls to the others for help but, of` - **l**

**317-3-2**

> 318-3-2 : `I want to move higher into the woods, climb a good tree,` - **a space**

Which gives us:

> bo l - Which makes no sense.

If they are `-1`:

**9-4-1**

> 8-4-1 : `around the woods looking for handouts, it became his official` - **a**

**188-1-14**

> 187-1-14 : `hand. What can it be? Not food surely. I unscrew the lid and I` - **n**

**59-3-59**

> 58-3-59 : `“Stand over here. Both of you,” says Haymitch, nodding to the` - **t** (Even though the `t` is on the next line, but that line only has 58 characters)

**189-2-27**

> 188-2-27 : `the ground. By her position, leaning up against the trunk of` - **n**

**317-3-2**

> 316-3-2 : `how she tried to take enough to stay alive but not enough that` - **o**

Which gives us:

> antno - Which makes no sense either.

Comment: You are close. Rethink what each of those numbers might mean.

Comment: In my answer, I assumed it was page-paragraph-word.  Maybe page-paragraph-character?

Comment: Letter, not character, perhaps?

Comment: @Deusovi [Someone answered this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/40701/9993) and got something that has some meaning.

Answer (score 1):

#### Partial Answer

Using the information in the comments (the PDF book link and the assertion that the page numbers there are off by one), and assuming this is a book cipher, we are left with the following words:

> **Leave if had to not**

I'm not sure where to go from there.