# “Tell Your Friends” - a mysterious e-mail that landed in my inbox [Part 4 of 6]

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Now that you've managed to beat [Part 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/40504/2135), we can move on to Part 4! Yey!

---

Immediately after entering the correct word in the prompt, you receive a new message on your screen...

```
Congratulations on solving Part 3! Now, we can proceed... 
This one should be pretty simple.

Deep within a tree, three brothers sit. In which order must they be hit?
```

Your mysterious host is waiting...

---

This puzzle was written by the person running the [No Really It Is Me](https://noreallyitis.me) site. I have received permission from the OP to post this puzzle series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it could be

> 2, 3, 1, since it's a reference to the [Deku Scrub Brothers](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Deku_Scrub_Brothers) from The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time, which need to be hit in that order to be defeated.

Comment: Well, that would be it. Six minutes. Impressive.

Comment: A fellow Zelda fan, I must assume?

Comment: @CasperTheFriendlyCode OoT is actually the only one I've played so far, I've been meaning to get around to some others though!