# “Tell Your Friends” - a mysterious e-mail that landed in my inbox [Part 5 of 6]

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Now that [Part 4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40716/tell-your-friends-a-mysterious-e-mail-that-landed-in-my-inbox-part-4-of) was solved in six minutes' time....

---

Our mysterious host congratulates you on your quick solution, much berating the OP for taking 24 hours to solve it.

But, like everything, this puzzle shall go on! A new message appears on your screen:

```
-.-. ..- / -.-. / -.. .- -.- .-.-.- / --- .-.-.- .-.-.- -... / ..- --. .--. -.-- -.. .-.-.- .--. / -.-. -.-- / -.-. --- / -..- ..-. / --- -.-- .- -... . -.-. -... .. / .-. -... / -.-- -.. .-.-.- / --- -.. .-. --. -. . .-.-.- .--. --- / .-. ..-
```

Our host eagerly awaits your reply.

---

This puzzle was originally written by the person running the [No Really It Is Me](https://noreallyitis.me) site. In the state where I received the original puzzle, it was unsolvable without an extreme guess or recognizing the solution quickly. I have received permission from the original poster of this puzzle to mirror it here.

Comment: How did you receive the puzzle? What's different about it now?

Comment: @Deusovi The original puzzle did not have the `.` character transposed correctly.

Comment: Next month, I'll have to be a lot more challenging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Morse says

> CU C DAK. O..B UGPYD.P CY CO XF OYABECBI RB YD. ODRGNE.PO RU

If you read that as if

> it was typed on a QWERTY keyboard where the buttons were mislabelled as Dvorak

you get

> IF I HAVE SEEN FURTHER IT IS BY STANDING ON THE SHOULDERS OF

so the solution is

> GIANTS.

(Not sure what the ciphertext-plaintext mapping's pattern is though.)

Comment: While this is the correct answer, there is a specific cipher (?) used for the decoding. Now, I'm not sure on the site policy, but I'll refrain from accepting this until the proper cryptogram is solved. As you're the all-powerful mod in this situation, let me know if this is in violation of the site policy/trends.

Comment: @Deusovi - add my answer to yours, so that Kaz can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @YowE3K: Done! I figured it was something similar, but couldn't be bothered to look up the layout.

Comment: @KazWolfe: Nope, no violation there.