# “Tell Your Friends” - a mysterious e-mail that landed in my inbox [Part 6 of 6]

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Now that [part 5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40718/tell-your-friends-a-mysterious-e-mail-that-landed-in-my-inbox-part-5-of) was completed in such a short time that I just stood there with my mouth agape...

---

Your mysterious host sends his regards and yet one more message:

> Congratulations on reaching the sixth and final part of our little puzzle! Solve this and you'll finally get the antidote to the poison you've ingested! Haha! (Just kidding, but good job!)
>
> ```
> Green Tunic
> Entrepreneur Raccoon
> Tiny Aliens
> Large Primates
> Artistic Wolf
> Galactic Canine
> ```
>
> I will send a hint if there's no solution after a while...

---

This puzzle was originally written by the person running the [No Really It Is Me](https://noreallyitis.me) site. I have received permission to mirror this puzzle here from the original poster. I have, however, made minor cosmetic tweaks to this particular puzzle

Comment: maybe each sentence should have a synonym? like `Large Primates` might be `Chimpanzee`. Or maybe they are a reference to cartoons? `Green Tunic` --> `Link`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remembering the previous reference to Zelda and [Miquel's comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40727/tell-your-friends-a-mysterious-e-mail-that-landed-in-my-inbox-part-6-of-6#comment120175_40727), a first attempt at an answer:

- Green Tunic

  > Link, from [*The Legend of Zelda*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda)
- Entrepreneur Raccoon

  > Tom Nook, from [*Animal Crossing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Crossing) (thanks @LeppyR64)
- Tiny Aliens

  > Pikmin, from the [game of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pikmin)
- Large Primates

  > Donkey Kong, from the [series of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donkey_Kong)
- Artistic Wolf

  > Amaterasu, from [*Ōkami*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%8Ckami)
- Galactic Canine

  > Fox McCloud, from [*Star Fox*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Fox)

These are all

> Nintendo characters

If we take a

> letter from each of their associated games,

We get:

> Legend of **Z**elda
>  **A**nimal Crossing
>  **P**ikmin
>  **D**onky Kong
>  **O**kami
>  **S**tar Fox

Spelling out the answer  to the puzzle:

> **ZAPDOS**
>
>  [image]

Comment: You're bang on.  It's Tom Nook for the raccoon.

Comment: So if we get the first letter from each one... LTPDAS --> http://www.whatletter.com/6/what-does-stand-for/ltpdas

Comment: @2012rcampion or *something* haha pretty sure it might be the answer

Comment: Zapdos is indeed a Pokémon and I think you should post that as a separate answer

Comment: @Falc No, not a separate answer. It's part of this answer.

Comment: @Mithrandir I added it to the answer after Falc posted his comment (and then deleted my original comment to avoid spoilers)